# Moving Button Continuous Movements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, logic, uianimation

I have a button in a game that moves to the side when hovered.
However when the mouse is inside the original bounding box of the sprite while outside of the actual bounding box, the button moves back and forth between the 2 locations (Spazzing out?).

Heres a screenshot:

http://oi57.tinypic.com/2dubjiv.jpg
    Not enough rep to post img :(

The first image is the button initially, second is hovered, and third is in between the 2 regions.

Heres the simple code I used:

```
void OnMouseEnter(){
    gameObject.MoveTo (targetPos, time, 0);
    // time == 0.5F
}

void OnMouseExit(){
    gameObject.MoveTo (initialPos, time, 0);
}
```

I know moving buttons are rarely used and not recommended but still, anyone has any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after experimenting for a bit I found that the trick was to use a longer bounding box, and not update it. This meant not using OnMouseEnter and OnMouseExit and using bounds.IntersectRay instead.